# How to apply custom CSS to boostrap columns only for specific width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap to lay out my website.  I have an element that I would like to look a certain way on mobile, and a different way on desktop.  I could edit the CSS for the corresponding `col-lg-7` (or whatever) class.  However, I am using that class elsewhere.  How can I get custom styling for only the mobile (or desktop) view?

**For example (just an example, not interested in borders specifically):**
What I would like is for the border to exist on the first "cell" ONLY in desktop mode, and for there to be a border on *no cells* in mobile mode.  I have tried using the `.col-lg-7.only-lg-styling` css selector, but this doesn't work, because bootstrap keeps all of the classes and sets the styling dynamically.

What CSS can I use so that, in desktop mode, there is a border, but in mobile mode, there is no border?

[Example: (click for jsfiddle... you can resize the display in jsfiddle to see xs vs lg)](https://jsfiddle.net/sn9uzx3v/)

```css
.col-lg-7.only-lg-styling {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-12 only-lg-styling">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 only-lg-styling">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-12">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You're just looking for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and I suggest aligning yours with [those of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) for consistent behavior. Keep in mind that Bootstrap is "mobile first", so set your smallest screen styles first and override as it gets larger.

Comment: In case it's not clear, there's no Bootstrap mechanism for fastening custom styles to their breakpoints (short of [display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)).